# Showing that $y=P\cos(\ln(t))+Q\sin(\ln(t))$ satisfies $t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}+y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that, if $P$ and $Q$ are constants and $$y = P\cos(\ln(t)) + Q\sin(\ln(t))$$
>   then
>   $$t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}+y=0$$

Comment: Umm.... what is "Int"?

Comment: Is it correct now, with logarithm.?

Comment: That's a very misleading title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P$ and $ Q $ are constant, thus by chaine rule differentiation,

$$y'=-P\sin(\ln(t))\frac 1t +Q\cos(\ln(t))\frac 1t$$

$$y''=-P\cos(\ln(t))\frac{1}{t^2}+$$

$$P\sin(\ln(t))\frac{1}{t^2}-$$
$$Q\sin(\ln(t))\frac{1}{t^2}-$$
$$Q\cos(\ln(t))\frac{1}{t^2}$$

$$t^2y''=-y-ty'$$

Comment: thank you for the help

Comment: Why downvoting this answer?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = P\cos(\ln(t)) + Q\sin(\ln(t)),$$
Change the variable $t=e^x$
$$y = P\cos(x) + Q\sin(x),$$
Is a solution of a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients. The polynomial characteristic is:
$$r=\pm i \implies r^2+1=0$$
The differential equation is:
$$y''+y=0$$
change the variable $t=e^ x$:
$$y'=\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {dy}{dt}\dfrac {dt}{dx}=t\dfrac {dy}{dt}$$
Do the same for $y''$
$$\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}=ty'_t+t^2y''_t$$
Therefore the DE becomes:
$$t^2y''_t+ty'_t+y=0$$